# animation get laggy in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I have a problem in my splash screen.
My Splash screen is very simple one, it's just two animation.
I tested it by my self and it was OK on the Sony z3 compact and HTC m8.
But a friend of mine told me my splash screen animation get laggy in Sony ZR and HTC 816, and when i say leggy i mean its like u run a 4k video on a Celeron CPU :|  .
all of this phone use android 5 or higher like 5.1.

SplashScreen.java:

```
packagetest.test.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.eftimoff.androidplayer.Player;
import com.eftimoff.androidplayer.actions.property.PropertyAction;


public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    View logo;
    RelativeLayout text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(R.layout.splesh_screen);
        logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
        text = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.text);

        animate(logo);
        animate2(text);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                 Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();


            }
        }, 4500);






    }
    public void animate(View animating_view) {


        AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);//false mean dont share interpolators
        Animation anim_push_down, anim_fade_in, anim_push_up;

        anim_push_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.push_down);
        anim_fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in);

        anim_push_down.setDuration(1400);
        anim_fade_in.setDuration(1200);
        s.addAnimation(anim_push_down);
        s.addAnimation(anim_fade_in);

        animating_view.startAnimation(s);


    }
    public void animate2(View animating_view) {


        AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);//false mean dont share interpolators
        Animation anim_splash_push_up_in, anim_fade_in, anim_push_up;

        anim_splash_push_up_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.anim_splash_push_up_in);
        anim_fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in);

        anim_splash_push_up_in.setDuration(1700);
        anim_fade_in.setDuration(1900);
        s.addAnimation(anim_splash_push_up_in);
        s.addAnimation(anim_fade_in);

        animating_view.startAnimation(s);







    }
}
```

Comment: try new animation framework introduced in Api 11. Animator!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as "Muhammad Babar" said, I used the new android animation framework, and also, use the other sizes of my images.
so, now, everything is smooth and lovely.